# Is there a way to get a 7 day calendar view of assigned user in Event page

Tags: apex, visualforce, configuration

I am trying to see if i can get a 7 day of view of the calendar of the assigned user. The idea is to allow the user to choose a date based on the availability for the next 7 days
Is this possible?

[image]
I couldnt find any way of configuring that in the event layouts.

If this is not possible through configurations, is it possible through VF page? Any pointers would be great help.

Thanks